# Android GridView not standard divider

Tags: android, gridview

How to make divider in `GridView` like this?
I don't have enough rating to post images, please look at the picture:

[image: picture]

I didn't find answer in other questions at stackoverflow.com.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have sample code, neither do I. Lol. But how I remembered using Gridview, is that you would have a layout for the gridview itself and a layout for the cells. So to make the cell similar to your image, I would use relative layout; put on 4 'view' elements and a textview; 1 view should have attribute align parent top to true, the others bottom, right, and left to true; textview should have center in parent as true. There.

**Update:**
So try this cell layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Item"
        android:textSize="100sp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, I tried to do it, but it isn't that I want, you can see it in this image: http://imgur.com/aoH22QV

Comment: @promerbay so added code for the cell. please try it out. thank you.